# Use jquery validate plugin to : some select box option value must be chosen

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

First, i have an array that has all the option value must be selected e.g.

```
$require=array('volvo','saab');
```

Then ,

> i have x number of select box, x is a number less or equal to 
>   number of option value

Then i have the selectbox e.g.

```
<select name ="car" id="0">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name ="car" id="1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name ="car" id="2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

In this case , i need to check:

1) No duplicate select value

2)The value in array must be selected one and only one.

I can figure out the checking of unqiue value in select box , but how about the second condition ?

Thank you

```
Using the above case as an example

id = 0 , value = volvo
id = 1 , value = Mercedes
id = 2 , value = Audi

Not valid

id = 0 , value = saab
id = 1 , value = Audi
id = 2 , value = volvo

valid
```

Comment: u r asking if i select Volvo in id=0 then volvo should not be selected in id=1,id=2

Comment: Can you explain your 2nd condition properly with example.

Comment: no problem, i have add an example

Comment: @ThulasiRam, sure, that means there is not unique and it should be invalid

Comment: @user782104 still i did not get u. what is the relation between these three drop down list?

Comment: @ThulasiRam, the value should be unique , that means, if drop list 1 choose saab, the other lists can not select saab. Also, two of three must be volvo and saab. (in the array $require)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st suggestion, please don't use same name for more than one HTML element, its invalid html.
If you just doing it for the selector purpose, use class attribute instead instead.

I went ahead with "divide and rule" approach, its not very well optimized, but it works.

Well I tried to divide your solution in 2 steps:

Step 1: Check for uniqueness

```
//val is the array of values from each select box
function checkUnique(val){
    var cnt = val.length;
    for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++){
        for(j = i+1; j < cnt; j++){
            if(val[i] == val[j]){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Step 2: Check for the required values for validation

```
// array of required values:
var required = ['saab', 'volvo'];
function validate(){
    var val = [];
    $("select[name=car]").each(function(){
        val.push(this.value);
    });
    if(checkUnique(val)){
        var cnt = required.length;
        var cnt2 = val.length;
        for(k = 0; k < cnt; k++){
            var flag = false;
            for(l = 0; l < cnt2; l++){
                if(required[k] == val[l]){
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if(flag){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I call validate function on document load and all events of selectbox change event:

```
function showMsg(){
    var msg = (validate())?'OK':'NOT OK';
    // added html DIV tag with id="result" to show the status on change events
    $("#result").html(msg);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    showMsg();
});
$("select[name=car]").change(function () {
        showMsg();
});
```

You can check the complete example here on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LCxJw/

Comment: Can I 'convert' the php arrary to jquery one?

Comment: yeh sure you can use `var required = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray); ?>;` you will be converting it into json object, you can loop through it using `for(x in required){required[x];}`

Answer (score 1):

This is the jQuery way:

```
$('select[name=car]').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var selected = $(this).val();
    console.log( id + ' ' + selected );
    $('select[name=car] option').each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('selected');
    });
    $('#'+id).find('option[value='+selected+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

I would recommend you to start your selects with a first option like:

```
<option>Select</option>
```

Comment: Thanks. but i am looking for jquery validate rules one, thanks your help.